# Laravel aggregate with mongo db give me error

Tags: laravel, mongodb, aggregate

I'm using Mongodb, I have an issue when I am running a query in Mongo it succeeds but when I am to re-write it and run it in Laravel I'm getting this error:

> A pipeline stage specification object must contain exactly one field.

this is my query which I do in Mongodb directly  and working perfectly :

```
db.logss.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$ApplicationName",
            "count": {$sum: 1}
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: {"count": -1}
    }
]);
```

this is my code in Laravel but give me that error

```
return $collection->aggregate([
    [
        '$group'    => [
            '_id'   => '$ApplicationName',

            'count' => [
                '$sum'  => 1
            ]
        ],
        ['$sort' => ['count' => -1]] 
    ]
]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Mongo error, Mongo is complaining about the pipeline not being in the "correct" format, I think here you just missed a parentheses, try this:

```
return $collection->aggregate([
    [
        '$group'    => [
            '_id'   => '$ApplicationName',

            'count' => [
                '$sum'  => 1
            ]
        ]
    ],
    ['$sort' => ['count' => -1]]
]);
```